Search Youtube API don't work for some channel
I'm trying to use the youtube search api and I have a weird behaviour.
If I'm using this url (you can't use without an api key) :
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=UCVG8kYUf9q53DNHJqq_daew&type=channel&maxResults=5
I don't have any result, even if the channel UCVG8kYUf9q53DNHJqq_daew do exist.
I can try with other channel, like this one : UCzbuINvbG-NCDVtQkfz_lcQ and it works
So I don't get it. Is there some subtleties on this API ?

YouTube Data API v3 Search: list endpoint has many issues, you are just facing one of them. If you know the channel id, why not using YouTube Data API v3 Channels: list endpoint?

yes, that's indeed the solution I've used. It breaks one use case but it's a rare use case. So, it's ok

@HugoLassiège since you have the channel_id, you can use this URL: https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=<CHANNEL_ID> and get from there the name of the channel and the latest uploaded videos. With this URL, you can save quota - which the search.list endpoint consumes.

@MauricioAriasOlave that's indeed a very good point. However I need some stats (subscribers, views etc...), so I have to use the API instead.
But thanks a lot for this hint
